# javac is unable to find import

Tags: java, javac, java-bytecode-asm

I am having trouble compiling a file with javac.

My command to compile is:

```
C:\Work>javac -classpath "%CLASSPATH%;C:\Users\Me\Downloads\asm-4.1-bin\asm-4.1\src" wDump.java
```

Results in:

```
wDump.java:3: error: package org.objectweb.asm.attrs does not exist
import org.objectweb.asm.attrs.*;
^
1 error
```

That package most certainly DOES exist. Its in the same directory tree as all the other ASM imports. attrs is an empty package that contains a single HTML document.

wDump.java file also contains

```
import org.objectweb.asm.*;
```

Which is found by the compiler without any problems.

If I comment the problem import out(org.objectweb.asm.attrs.*),
the file compiles successfully. I should also note that the Eclipse compiler compiles this file successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You might need [`sourcepath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) not the `classpath`

Comment: `javac -sourcepath "C:\Users\Me\Downloads\asm-4.1-bin\asm-4.1\src" wDump.java` gave the same result

Comment: what is there in src directory

Comment: It contains the ASM 4.1 source. Directory structure is `src\org\objectweb\asm` The folder `asm` contains folders attrs, commons, optimizer, signature, tree, util, xml

Answer (score 0):

use the following:

```
javac \
-sourcepath src \
-your_jar_path/your.jar:. \
your_class_path/your.java \
-d classes
```

Comment: Does `src` represent the full path to the source folder? Also, do you want `your_class_path` preceded by `cp`?

Comment: follow this link and see bottom of the page https://github.com/coolaj86/json-examples/tree/master/java/jackson

Answer (score 0):

If your code is compiling when commenting out the `import` line, then you don't need it and can remove it.

If you want to use it, check that `attrs` is the correct name of the package, as it seems that `import org.objectweb.asm.*;` is working. And check that `attrs` is effectively a package and that the folder is physically existing inside of `asm` folder. You can also check that the class files are present inside the `attrs` folder.

The `attrs` folder in the `asm` source zip contains only an html page without any class inside. Try to remove this folder (you can save it before in other directory if you are not sure) and to generate again the `imports` through the `ASMifier` tool. If folder doesn't exist, maybe the tool won't generate automatically the import.

For your information, you shouldn't use external source code to compile your code, except if you are modifying these external sources. Use instead the jar files, added to your classpath, to compile your code. **In the asm-all-4.1 jar file, there is no attrs folder.**

Comment: That import is auto-generated by the tool I am using(ASMifier). I'd prefer not to comment it out each time since I need to compile many files.

Comment: I just downloaded the asm-4.1-bin.zip file from the OW2 web page: src.zip, contained in the asm zip, contains an `attrs` folder, but there is nothing else than an html page inside: it's not a package. Check the content of `attrs` folder in your `src` directory.

Comment: Try to use the `asm-all-4.1.jar` contained in the `lib/all` folder of the `asm` zip file to compile your code. In this jar file, the `attrs` folder doesn't exist and maybe the tool won't generate the `import` for that package. Don't use external sources to compile your code unless you want to modify them.

Comment: Good idea but it didnt work. The tool in the `asm-all-4.1.jar` still generated the `attrs` import

Comment: You surely are doing something wrong with this tool and should read carefully the documentation. Anyway, you can try to have a fake package: just try to put an empty class file in the correct folder and try to compile with the `import`.